# jquery show and hide image after x seconds

Tags: jquery

I want to show and image for 2 seconds and the hide it to show a chart. I have the part were the chart appers after 2 seconds but I don't know how to put the image.

```
$("li").click(function(){
    //Toggle List
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).next("div").stop('true','true').slideToggle();
    //SHOW image for 2 seconds and then HIDE IT
    var did = $(this).attr('id');
    var graphic;

    if($(this).next("div").html() == '')
        {
        graphic = '';
            $.ajax({
               url: 'pulse.php?did='+did, success: function(data)
             {
             graphic = data;
             }
        });
    }

    //Here I show the chart after 2 seconds pulling the data from pulse.php...
delay(function(){               
    $("#"+did).next("div").html(graphic);
    }, 2000 );
});


    //Delay function
var delay = (function(){
var timer = 0;
         return function(callback, ms){
         clearTimeout (timer);
         timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
     };
})();
```

Comment: it would help if you format your code nicely and put some comments or HTML in context

Comment: Where is `delay()` defined? Seems to be the same as `setTimeout`? (As compared to the jQuery animation `.delay()` function?) Can you not add `$("#yourIMG").show()` at the start of your code and then put `$("#yourIMG").hide()` in the same place where you show the chart? Also, you seem to be getting the chart via Ajax, so why not hide the image and show the chart in the Ajax success callback? (Using a delay to give Ajax time to complete isn't a very neat or reliable method.)

Answer (score 0):

If what you have is already working, I suppose it's just a matter of showing and hiding an image element at the right places:

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $("#imageElementID").show(); //show image on click
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).next("div").stop('true','true').slideToggle();
    //SHOW image for 2 seconds and then HIDE IT
    var did = $(this).attr('id'), graphic;
    if ($(this).next("div").html() === '') {
        graphic = '';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'pulse.php?did='+did, 
            success: function(data) {
                graphic = data;
            }
        });
    }
    delay(function(){               
        $("#imageElementID").hide(); //hide image after some sort of delay function ?
        $("#"+did).next("div").html(graphic);
    }, 2000 );
});​
```